# LazyColumn recomposes the element multiple times on scroll. Performance issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, compose-recomposition

In the Log i can see if i just touch the list it will recompose it multiple times. It works fine and print "!!!" once every time new row appears if i run composable function separatly from app, but inside composeView it goes crazy and print it a lot of times.

```
val listState = rememberLazyListState()
LazyColumn(
    state = listState,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(colorResource(R.color.dark_blue))
) {
    itemsIndexed(items, { index, item -> index) }) { index, item ->
        println("!!!")
        TableRow(item)
    }
}
```

the function itself only runs once

Comment: How are you setting up your `ComposeView`?

Comment: `<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout`
    `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`     
        `<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView`
and all this is inside motionlayout screen.
i tried to remove coordinatorLayout and it didn't help